# Where can you find how much each country pays to the UN?

Tags: united-nations, reference-request, data-sources

Where is a trustworthy site that shows how much each country (not just the major countries) has payed to the UN every year for the past 5-10 years. I have looked on the internet and the UN website but could not find it.

Comment: https://www.un.org/en/ga/contributions/honourroll.shtml was the second hit on Google.

Comment: @MartinSchröder what did you look up, that didn’t show up for me. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Google results and ranking sometimes are different among users.

Comment: Are you interested only in payments to the UN proper, or would you include finding for other agencies such as UNICEF, the WFP, and so on?  If you include agencies, are you interested only in funding from government sources, or are you also interested in private donations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned [in the comments](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/63083/where-can-you-find-how-much-each-country-pays-to-the-un#comment252620_63083), [this UN page](https://www.un.org/en/ga/contributions/honourroll.shtml) says how much each country payed the UN for the regular budget.